# finding an equation from a graph

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

So I am confused on figuring out how to make an equation out of the graph I am given. It is question 7 I am referring to.  The coordinates I have on the graph are (3,0)(5,4)(7,-4) and there is no negative x-axis. the graph looks like a possible sinusoidal graph. I was just wondering if anyone knew how I would find the equation to graph or what formulas to use.[image]

Comment: Maybe the 7 should be a 9?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's actually a sinus we can write a general sinus formula like:

f(x) = k*Sin(ax + p) + t
where you can already from the fact that the max and min amplitude are the same determine that t = 0 
and that the amplitude is 4 -> k = 4

After you'll have to determine the phase p and the frequency ratio a

phase:
(1) x=3 : Sin(a*3 + p) = 0 -> 3a + p = 0
Frequency:
Distance between a maximum and the adjacent minimum is 2 (7-5)
For a 'normal' sinus that is PI or 180, depending on what degree system being used.
-> PI/(7-5) -> a=PI/2 (2)

Put this knowledge into (1) gives you:

(1) + (2): 3a + p = 0 -> 3/2*PI + p = 0 -> p = -3/2*PI

So the equation is:
f(x) = 4*Sin(PI/2 * x - 3/2*PI)    , assuming radians

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please use MathJax to format your answers, as it looks much nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this looks like a sinusoidal graph. So, since the function value is $0$ for $x=3$, let us admit an equation $$y(x)=a \sin [b (x-3)]$$ Now you have two other points which then lead to two equations for the two unknowns $a$ and $b$. You then have $$y(5)=a \sin (2 b)=4$$ $$y(7)=a \sin (4 b)=-4$$ If you compute the ratio of both equations, $a$ disappears and you have a simple equation (which simplifies a lot) in $b$. When you knw $b$, plug its value in any of the two equations to obtain the values of $a$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a flipped $\cos x$ graph (y-intercept is negative) so I will start with $f(x)=-\cos x$. An amplitude of $4$ is applied, so now we have $f(x)=-4\cos(x)$. There is a phase shift of $1$, so now we have $f(x)=-4\cos(x-1)$. The period is $8\pi$, so the inside of the $\cos$ function has to be multiplied by $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. The equation of the graph is:
$$f(x)=-4\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}(x-1)\right)$$
$$\displaystyle \boxed{f(x)=-4\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}x-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)}$$

Comment: this seems pretty accurate but when i substitute the x coordinates they are just slightly off but I would assume it is still correct. How did you get a period of 8 though?

Comment: @rick First, notice that the last point was supposed to be $(9,-4)$ and not $(7,-4)$. Now we can deduce that the points follow this pattern: $(1,-4)$, $(3,0)$, $(5,4)$, $(7,0)$, $(9,-4)$, $(11,0)$... We want to find points with the same y-coordinates to deduce the period. Let's choose $(3,0)$, $(11,0)$. $(3,0)$ is the beginning of the period, and $(11,0)$ is the end of the period. Now, these points are $8$ units away from each other. So the period is $8$.

Comment: got it I understand I just didn't realize you changed the original 7 to a 9 that's what was confusing me